# Changing the text of the Cancel button in the default TouchID dialog

Tags: ios, touch-id

My iOS app uses TouchID to unlock some secure services. The designer doesn't want the Cancel button's text to read Cancel, but to rather read "Setup Later." I can see how to change the text of the default "Enter Password" button, that's easy:

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
context.localizedFallbackTitle = @"Speak Friend and Enter";
```

But I don't see an LAContext property that I can set to change the Cancel button label. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think you can change the cancel button text. i have tried too.. let me know if you have found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can from version 10.0.

**Documentation:**

[LocalizedCancelTitle](https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication/lacontext/1643658-localizedcanceltitle)

Example of use:

```
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 10){
     [myContext setLocalizedCancelTitle:@"Your text"];
}
```